# What are the Benefits of using a DataTable datatype

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2012

I have a C# program that will read a SQL Server-2012 table, TableA, to retrieve hundreds to thousands of records which have a null value in the name column. Those same records will then be used to call an API to retrieve additional info for each record, for example name. Next, the program will perform an update to TableA on the Name column using the retrieved info from the previous API call.

It was suggested to me that I should use a DataTable / TableType to accomplish this. My question is what is the advantage if any of using this suggested method versus just updating each record in SQL server one at a time after the API call that retrieves the name ?

I know that if I update each record one at a time and a problem occurs before all of the records have been processed then at least the records processed up to that point will be committed to the SQL database. I'm not sure how the DataTable would handle this type of scenario.

Comment: "at least the records processed up to that point will be committed to the SQL database..." that's not the case if you use a transaction.

Comment: "It was suggested to me that I should use a DataTable / TableType to accomplish this." - In 2005, maybe. There are *astonishingly few cases* where people should really still be using `DataTable` today. They *do still exist*, but this *is not one of them*. Will it work? Possibly; probably. Will it have problems like you describe; sure; it'll also be pretty horribly inefficient, and not at all compatible with streaming through the data.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if you make a transaction that covers hundreds of thousands of rows and possibly external API access: then expect it to fail horribly

Comment: @MarcGravell so would you suggest my program performing the following flow: Sql read (retrieve all rows)  ---> API Call (one at a time)  ---> SQL update (one at a time)                                                             versus SQL read (all rows) ---> API Call (one at a time) ---> SQL update (once using DataTable) ?

Comment: @Jason well, I wouldn't "retrieve all rows" - I would probably use an open non-buffered reader to do that *without* having to load them all at once, *and* I'd probably do a `select top 1000 ...` or similar so I'm never trying to load huge volumes. Obviously this might need consideration if some rows will never be completed i.e. will stay `null` - because you'd need a way other than `where foo is null` to fetch the next page; perhaps `where foo is null and id > @lastKnownId order by id`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Without knowing the context, it's likely that they were referring to a table-valued parameter. It's a SQL parameter type that allows you to send rows of data. .NET code creates the parameter using a `DataTable`. This might apply to the second step in which you update records. You can use this when performing updates for multiple records with one call instead of executing a stored procedure over and over for each individual record.

Comment: @ScottHannen yes the DataTable was suggested for me to use when I'm doing the table update. I have never used this method before so I was unclear of the benefit of doing it this way other than we can do the update with one call versus multiple calls.